# Custom Keyboard Replace default keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I hava two EditText in a Scorllview，Using different Keyboard，a custom keyboard and a default keyboard.  like this (The pseudo-code)：

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScorllView 

   <EditText
   android:id="@+id/EditText1"/>

   <EditText
   android:id="@+id/EditText2"/>

</ScorllView>

   <CustomKeyboardView/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When default keyboard is showing , I click EditText2 ,set CustomKeyboardView visible and disable default keyboard. the CustomKeyboardView is above the default keyboard, then default keyboard quickly disappeared  and CustomKeyboardView go down. just like splash screen. And the scorllView can't be sliding. Please help me, thanks.